# Background color of eclipse error popups

Tags: linux, eclipse

When you hover over a error in the source editor from within Eclipse, it will show a little overlay suggesting how to fix it.  This is terribly useful for importing classes, and I use it for this quite a lot. However, on Linux the colour scheme is horrendous, its thin blue writing on a dark grey background, and its borderline impossible to read.

How can I fix this from within eclipse? All "solutions" I seen so far to this problem, involves modifying your gtk theme. Which is a bit ridiculous (why would I break everything else to fix one faulty program).

Comment: Java Swing applications always look awful on Linux. See if Eclipse has a custom skin option under preferences.

Comment: If this was a swing app I wouldn't have this problem mate :) Its SWT-GTK, unfortunately, compared to SWT, Swing looks like Natalie Portman (and SWT looks like Gollum)

Comment: Oh. I feel bad for you. My suggestion? Don't use the bloated Java app anyway. If you want it, but looking good, give a shot at the standalone version of Aptana Studio. Otherwise, find a different editor. Try VIM!

Comment: Are you aware that Aptana uses SWT and java? ;p And I do use VIM, for Latex, scripting and the occasional bit of C++ work :) Its no replacement for Eclipse when it comes to large scale Java development I'm afraid. If Eclipse would just look/run like it does on windows or OSX then everything would be perfect :/

Comment: I know Aptana is an Eclipse fork, that's why I suggested it because it seems to have good (not native, but still) looks on Linux.

Comment: aah makes sence :) it looks very very similar to "eclipse classic" but i suspect being swt-gtk based it will suffer the same flaws. In any-case, I kinda need to fix eclipse. Looking for alternative aren't really viable. I suppose I just need to beg my boss for a MacBook lol :D

Comment: I think you should stay on Linux (I say typing on my Mac, next to my Linux box) :).

Answer (score 1):

First suggestions - Use `Ctrl-Shift-O` to insert the correct imports.
Then later, set `On Save Actions` to automatically insert the correct imports. Then as you write new code, it `Ctrl-S`, which will also automatically compile the code again and show you any compile issues! Very helpful.

Second - Use an [Eclipse theme!](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/)

Comment: Thanks alot for the On Save actions tip, +1 for that :) It super helpful, but it doesn't answer the question though, of how to fix the background color, so I wont accept the answer. Hope you understand :) And just so you know, I used alot of themes, both color themes and normal themes jeeyul's chrome theme is the best i tried so for, but even that doesn't fix the issue. Nor does it make eclipse even remotely close to looking "alright". Try running eclipse on mac or windows, the problem is, regardless of the theme being used, SWT still uses GWT and it does it very poorly.

Comment: Oh! I thought a theme should have fixed the box color :( Have you tried the Dark Juno theme for Eclipse 4.x it seems to change all the colors for my Eclipse, including the popup boxes. Sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: you been very helpful! Im just a bitter old man when it comes to eclipse on linux :D I'll try the dark juno theme now :)

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solution to this, and I reckon I will post it here in-case other people might find it useful.

I created a custom gtkrc file, containing the following

```
style "eclipse-tooltips"
{
    xthickness  = 8
    ythickness  = 4

    bg[NORMAL]    = {0.8, 0.8, 0.8}
    fg[NORMAL]    = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    bg[SELECTED]  = {0.8, 0.8, 0.8}
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*"       style "eclipse-tooltips"
```

and then started eclipse using

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/path/to/custom/gtkrc eclipse
```